# #1062 — Дублирующаяся запись '2-6' по ключу 'PRIMARY', как исправить?

Tags: mysql, symfony, symfony4, easyadmin

Похожие вопросы были, но в них я так и не нашел как решить свою проблему.

Изучаю Symfony, и наткнулся на такую проблему, система Тэгов не хочет работать, ошибка в Mysql, когда добавляешь через Админку (EasyAdmin) не работает, добавляешь в ручную через phpMyAdmin то вылетает ошибка 1062, но что самое интересное данные добавляться.

Структура таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка 1062
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что непонятного в тексте ошибки?

Comment: Не понятно как исправить.

Comment: Не вставлять строку с ключом, который уже есть

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Ну судя по тому, какие скриншоты ты добавил - не надо нажимать кнопку "добавить"

Comment: А если мне надо добавить, то как быть?

Comment: добавлять другие значения, кроме тех, которые уже добавлены

Comment: Ошибка прямо пишет - строка с такими значениями **уже есть**, зачем ее добавлять ее раз?

Comment: Даже если очистить таблицу и добавить новые знамения эта ошибка все равно выскакивает

Comment: *Даже если очистить таблицу* Чудеса рассказываете...